# Golang pass a slice of structs to a stored procedure as a array of user defined types

Tags: postgresql, go

I have a slice of structs that I want to pass into a stored procedure to be used as an array of user defined types t but I can't figure out a way of doing this is in Go.

For example the structs in go:

```
type a struct {
    ID           int `db:"id"`
    Name         string `db:"name"`
    Created      time.Time `db:"created"`
    IsNew        bool   `db:"is_new"`
}
```

And the create statement for the user defined type

```
CREATE TYPE custom_type AS
(
    id int,
    name varchar,
    created timestamp,
    is_new boolean
)
```

and then the stored procedure

```
create or replace procedure custom_procedure(
   input custom_type[]
)
```

So far I have tried doing

```
func Save(records []a) error {
_, err := p.client.Exec("CALL custom_procedure($1)", pq.Array(records))
return err
}
```

but I just get an error "sql: converting argument $1 type: unsupported type a, a struct"

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to implement the [`driver.Valuer`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/driver/#Valuer) interface on the `a` type and have the `Value` method return a postgres composite type literal of the instance of `a`.

You can read this [documentation](https://postgresql.org/docs/13/interactive/rowtypes.html#id-1.5.7.24.6) on how to properly construct composite row type values. Just keep in mind that, since you're using `pq.Array`, which will quote the output of the `Value` method, you yourself SHOULD NOT put quotes around the output and also you SHOULD NOT use the ROW keyword.

For example:

```golang
type a struct {
    ID      int       `db:"id"`
    Name    string    `db:"name"`
    Created time.Time `db:"created"`
    IsNew   bool      `db:"is_new"`
}

func (v a) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    s := fmt.Sprintf("(%d,%q,%s,%t)",
        v.ID,
        v.Name,
        v.Created.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"),
        v.IsNew,
    )
    return []byte(s), nil
}
```